# Running distfit.fit.transform(X) without printing output

Tags: python, distribution

I am running

```
dist = distfit(todf=True)
result = dist.fit_transform(X)
```

in my jupyter notebook, and it is doing great at determining the best distribution model to use.

However, I am running it many times to find the best model for a lot of different datasets in a loop.

each time I run it, it prints the something similar to the following:

```
[distfit] >fit..
[distfit] >transform..
[distfit] >[norm      ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 1.38472e-05] [loc=207.254 scale=143.612]
[distfit] >[expon     ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 2.47818e-05] [loc=8.893 scale=198.361]
[distfit] >[pareto    ] [0.02 sec] [RSS: 2.47818e-05] [loc=-8589934583.107 scale=8589934592.000]
[distfit] >[dweibull  ] [0.25 sec] [RSS: 7.37942e-06] [loc=171.102 scale=98.853]
[distfit] >[t         ] [1.15 sec] [RSS: 6.81669e-06] [loc=173.632 scale=86.340]
[distfit] >[genextreme] [1.60 sec] [RSS: 1.69362e-05] [loc=49.180 scale=147.354]
[distfit] >[gamma     ] [0.32 sec] [RSS: 7.37843e-05] [loc=8.893 scale=4.298]
[distfit] >[lognorm   ] [0.47 sec] [RSS: 6.49175e-05] [loc=8.893 scale=2.729]
[distfit] >[beta      ] [0.61 sec] [RSS: 1.7421e-06] [loc=6.526 scale=393295040577159.438]
[distfit] >[uniform   ] [0.00 sec] [RSS: 6.0825e-05] [loc=8.893 scale=1962.657]
[distfit] >[loggamma  ] [0.30 sec] [RSS: 1.49077e-05] [loc=-44563.811 scale=6071.669]
[distfit] >Compute confidence interval [parametric]
[distfit] >Cleaning previous fitted model results..
```

since I am running this over and again it is creating quite a large output, is there a way to run fit_transform() without printing the result?
I am using the result variable afterwards to look at the results so the printed outcome is unneeded.

Thanks

Comment: You can simple add the `print("")` statement at the end of that particular cell in your Jupyter notebook. This will do what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 3):

```
dist.fit_transform(X, verbose = 0)
```